# Limit not working in INNER JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, limit, inner-join

Am sure this question has already been asked, but I can't help but wonder why the "LIMIT 3" in one of the INNER JOINS is only returning a single imgUrl for the specified avp.productID in the "ON clause"! Is that LIMITs do not work in INNER JOINs? What better way could I use to achieve this please?

```
$query = "SELECT
p.productID,
p.productDesc,
p.productQty,
p.productPr,
p.type,
p.gender,
p.date

From
products AS p
INNER JOIN(
    Select 
        c.productID, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.availCol) AS color_list 
    FROM
        availColors AS c GROUP BY c.productID) AS colors
        ON
            p.productID = colors.productID
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
            s.productID,
            GROUP_CONCAT(s.availSizes) AS size_list
        FROM
            availSizes AS s
        GROUP BY
            s.productID
    ) AS sizes
ON
    p.productID = sizes.productID
INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
            avp.productID,
            avp.productImg
        FROM
            availImg AS avp
        ORDER BY
            avp.productID
        LIMIT 3) AS images
ON
    images.productID =  p.productID
WHERE
    p.productID = ?
GROUP BY
    p.productID";
```

Comment: Your limited inner joined query does not specify a product id. It will being back the last 3 images for the first product ids. If product id 1 had 3 images and product id 2 had 3 images, that query would bring back the 3 images for product id 1 (which would then fail the ON condition), irrespective of whether you were searching for product id 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query has a sub query that returns 3 images, ordered by product id. This sub query doesn't check if the images belong to the product you are searching for so could easily bring back 3 images for a different product. This would result in the main query trying to do an inner join onto the sub query based on product id and finding no matching records.

As your 2 other sub queries only bring back a single row for each product id (due to the GROUP_CONCAT) and you appear to only want to check one product id at a time then I think you can solve this by just doing a normal join onto the images table (without a sub query) and putting the limit on the main query.

Like this:-

```
$query = "SELECT
        p.productID,
        p.productDesc,
        p.productQty,
        p.productPr,
        p.type,
        p.gender,
        p.date
From products AS p
INNER JOIN
(
    Select c.productID, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.availCol) AS color_list 
    FROM availColors AS c 
    GROUP BY c.productID
) AS colors
ON p.productID = colors.productID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.productID,
            GROUP_CONCAT(s.availSizes) AS size_list
    FROM availSizes AS s
    GROUP BY s.productID
) AS sizes
ON p.productID = sizes.productID
INNER JOIN availImg images
ON images.productID =  p.productID
WHERE p.productID = ?
ORDER BY images.productID, images.productImg
LIMIT 3";
```

However if you want to bring back multiple product ids then it becomes a bit more complicated. One solution would be to bring back the images with a generated sequence number for each product, and then check in the ON clause of the join that it is one of the first 3 images for a product:-

```
$query = "SELECT
        p.productID,
        p.productDesc,
        p.productQty,
        p.productPr,
        p.type,
        p.gender,
        p.date
From products AS p
INNER JOIN
(
    Select c.productID, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.availCol) AS color_list 
    FROM availColors AS c 
    GROUP BY c.productID
) AS colors
ON p.productID = colors.productID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.productID,
            GROUP_CONCAT(s.availSizes) AS size_list
    FROM availSizes AS s
    GROUP BY s.productID
) AS sizes
ON p.productID = sizes.productID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT avp.productID,
        avp.productImg,
        @seq:=IF(@prev_productID = avp.productID, @seq + 1, 1) AS seq,
        @prev_productID := avp.productID
    FROM availImg AS avp
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_productID:=0, @seq:=0) sub1
    ORDER BY avp.productID
) AS images
ON images.productID =  p.productID
AND images.seq <= 3
WHERE p.productID = ?";
```

Another possible method would be to use GROUP_CONCAT to get a comma separated list of image ids for each product, with SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the first 3 of these, then join that against the images table using FIND_IN_SET to get the rest of the image details:-

```
$query = "SELECT
        p.productID,
        p.productDesc,
        p.productQty,
        p.productPr,
        p.type,
        p.gender,
        p.date
From products AS p
INNER JOIN
(
    Select c.productID, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.availCol) AS color_list 
    FROM availColors AS c 
    GROUP BY c.productID
) AS colors
ON p.productID = colors.productID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.productID,
            GROUP_CONCAT(s.availSizes) AS size_list
    FROM availSizes AS s
    GROUP BY s.productID
) AS sizes
ON p.productID = sizes.productID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT avp.productID,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(avp.productImg), ',', 2), AS three_images_per_product
    FROM availImg AS avp
    GROUP BY avp.productID
) AS images
ON images.productID =  p.productID
INNER JOIN availImg
ON availImg.productID =  images.productID
AND FIND_IN_SET(availImg.productImg, images.three_images_per_product)
WHERE p.productID = ?";
```

Note that your original query doesn't actually have any image details in the SELECT clause, and also you had done a `GROUP BY p.productID` which would mean even if 3 images were found the query would only return one row per product id anyway.